# Multiple Inheritance and Bridge Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, multiple-inheritance, bridge

What's the point of implementing the Bridge pattern with multiple inheritance? The way GoF explains it in their Design Patterns book makes it seem counterintuitive to the Intent.

Also, why does multiple inheritance disqualify the implementation from being a true Bridge pattern?

Examples are much appreciated.

Comment: What does multiple inheritance have to do with the bridge-pattern? (MI isn't mentioned at all in the Wikipedia article on the pattern) - also, I note that many design-patterns in the GoF book are approaches to work-around limitations of the expressiveness of a language - if your language supports MI directly then that renders many patterns moot (e.g. the factory-pattern is popular in Java due to lack of support for function-pointers nor constructing instances of generic type arguments).

Comment: GoF explains that MI is a practical implementation for the Bridge pattern, and I have the same question (although I'm referring to the GoF book, not wikipedia). Also, GoF only explains C++ examples, but are there any other languages that provide MI that can still implement a true Bridge pattern with MI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all explained in the Implementation issues #4.

> *Using multiple inheritance*. You can use multiple inheritance in C++ to combine an interface with its implementation. For example, a class can inherit publicly from `Abstraction` and privately from a `Concretelmplementor`. But because this approach relies on static inheritance, it binds an implementation permanently to its interface. Therefore you can't implement a true Bridge with multiple inheritance—at least not in C++.

So...

> What's the point of implementing the Bridge pattern with multiple inheritance?

You can't.

> The way GoF explains it in their Design Patterns book makes it seem counterintuitive to the Intent.

It is. That's why you can't do it.

> why does multiple inheritance disqualify the implementation from being a true Bridge pattern?

"because this approach relies on static inheritance," [p. 156] and "Inheritance binds an implementation to the abstraction permanently, which makes it difficult to modify, extend, and reuse abstractions and implementations independently." [p. 151] ...which is the motivation for a Bridge.

---

Honestly, I'm not entirely sure why the GoF felt the need to bring up multiple inheritance in the Bridge chapter at all, but the conversation seems to go something like this.

- *GoF* : the Bridge Pattern is a more flexible alternative to a specific problem that would usually be solved using inheritance.
- *Hypothetical Reader* : ok, but what if I used *multiple* inheritance, hey?
- *GoF* : still *no*. It's still inheritance and still a static, inflexible relationship. Inheritance is inheritance.

Comment: Thanks, I had thought GoF was posing MI as a viable implementation, but this clears it up.